# How to exclude several values in a definition query

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, query, definition-query

I need to set up the definition query for a layer to exclude several types of values for a particular field. It is a status field that that has values such as Active, Inactive, Void, Received, etc. The definition query needs to be something along the lines of Status IS NOT "Inactive" OR "Received" OR "Void".

I've tried setting it up to Status IS NOT "Inactive" AND Status IS NOT "Received" AND Status IS NOT "Void"
and I've tried formatting it to IS NOT... OR...OR

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Definition queries in ArcGIS use the SQL database language, if you're having trouble with them I'd suggest a quick online SQL course. It's a lot easier to find SQL help than Definition Query help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the IN keyword to specify a list of potential values, such as `Status NOT IN ("Inactive", "Received", "Void",...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

[status] <> 'Active' AND [status] <> 'Inactive' AND [status] <> 'Void' AND [status] <> 'Received'

But Bjorn's answer seems more elegant.